# Power BI refreshing the online datasets when using APIs

Tags: api, token, refresh, powerbi

I am struggling with getting Power BI to be able to refresh from the published online side, it all works fine in power bi desktop.

At the moment I have a number of parameters setup to store the url and security credentials for obtaining the authorisation token for the api. This is so I can pass on to somebody else when i am finished and they can just swap the details out and refresh to use the same template.

[image: Parameters Setup]

I have a table that requests the token from the api.

[image: Get Token Table Code]

I then have 3 queries that use the token from that table to get data from our site.

[image: Get data code]

And the other 2 are pretty similar to this one.

Now these all work fine in the desktop but when i publish I see:

[image]

I don't know how I can get the data source credentials to be valid so it can refresh?

I did think about using the personal gateway instead, i installed it, it says connected and can be reached outside the network etc. but it never shows up in this view and I have no clue how to connect it or if i am doing something wrong with that either? I have only been using power bi for a couple of days so I have not got my head round everything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in each of those "Web ... Edit Credentials" entries, you are trying to mimic the setup for your PBIX file in Power BI Desktop, in the Data Source Settings window (File / Options and settings / Data Source settings).

For your scenario, it looks like you have coded your own authentication, so I expect you would set each "Web ... Edit Credentials" entry to **Anonymous**.

Comment: All of them are all set to Anonymous already, that is why i don't understand what the issue is?

Comment: Although your error message is different, perhaps you are getting tripped up by the silly static URL restriction described here: http://blog.datainspirations.com/2018/02/17/dynamic-web-contents-and-power-bi-refresh-errors/

Comment: Thanks, using http://blog.datainspirations.com/2018/02/17/dynamic-web-contents-and-power-bi-refresh-errors/ and https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2016/08/23/web-contents-m-functions-and-dataset-refresh-errors-in-power-bi/ I have now got round the credentials error which is a start. Had to only provide the top level url to the web contents function and then use the RelativePath to provide the rest and power bi started accepting it.

Comment: I am now getting a different error: "[Unable to combine data] Section1/Sites/Converted to Table references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination. Table: SitesData." when refreshing. I have tried separating out the query and the data manipulation in to different queries based on https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/11/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/ but still no joy. It is a shame that what works in desktop mode can't just work with no changes in the online mode as it is the same product

Comment: Assuming you know and trust all your data sources, in Power BI Desktop, go to File / Options and settings / Options / CURRENT FILE / Privacy and choose: Ignore the privacy levels ...